# Typescript casting with babel eslint parsing

Tags: typescript, babeljs, eslint, babel-eslint

I am getting some parsing errors after introducing ESLint into an existing Typescript codebase.

I have fixed most of the lint errors but `babel-eslint` as a parser throws quite a few errors like this:

```
  23:32  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

  21 |       return state.set(
  22 |         'callsInProgress',
> 23 |         (state.callsInProgress as any).filter(i => i !== action.payload)
     |                                ^
  24 |       );
  25 |     }
  26 |     case actions.API_RESET: {
```

I assume this is because `babel` does not understand the typecasting `as any`.

How do i get this through the parser?

My babel config is as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-typescript'],
  plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime', '@babel/plugin-transform-typescript']
};
```

Comment: Side note: It's a [*type assertion*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions), not a *cast*. Assertions aren't quite the same thing as casts.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Having a project that is using **babel**, **eslint** and **typescript** myself.

I recommend you to stop using `eslint-babel` and use `@typescript-eslint` instead/

[typescript-eslint](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint) is a project that has been started by the developers of Tslint *(now deprecated)*. It lint typescript code perfectly.

Here is an example of my eslint installed npm packages:

```
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.34.0",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.34.0",
"eslint": "^5.16.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.21.2",
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.3.0",
"eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.0",
```

Example of my `.eslintrc`:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',

  plugins: [
    '@typescript-eslint',
    'eslint-plugin-node',
  ],

  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
  ],

  parserOptions: {
    "ecmaVersion": 2020
  },

  rules: {
    "comma-dangle": ["error", {
      "arrays": "always-multiline",
      "objects": "always-multiline",
      "imports": "always-multiline",
      "exports": "always-multiline",
      "functions": "always-multiline",
    }],
  },

  env: {
    es6: true,
    browser: true,
    node: true,
  },

  parserOptions: {
    project: './tsconfig.json',
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
  },

  globals: {
    "global": false,
    "Promise": false,
  },
};
```

---

**NOTE**: I don't know if `eslint-babel` could be compatible with `@typescript-eslint`, maybe it does and you can use both.

Comment: Thanks.  This is currently where I going to as I find babel and it's ecosystem much harder to work with in comparison to just TypeScript.

Comment: Is `parserOptions` supposed to be in there twice?

Answer (score 15):

I finally agree with the accepted answer, after experienced the upgrade from JavaScript to TypeScript.
Post this answer to provide some additional key point.

1. @babel/eslint-parser (previously babel-eslint) can parse TS and let ESLint to work on TS.

> @babel/eslint-parser is a parser that allows ESLint to run on source
> code that is transformed by Babel.

2. @babel/eslint-parser can't and won't be able to check type issue on TypeScript

> since @typescript-eslint uses TypeScript under the hood, its rules can
> be made type-aware, which is something Babel doesn't have the ability
> to do.
> This I think is a must-have feature on TS.

See doc: https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/eslint/babel-eslint-parser#typescript

So basically, if your project is a pure TS project, just use `@typescript-eslint`

```
{
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
  ]
}
```

If your project has both TS and JS, you can use `@babel/eslint-parser` as well

```
{
  "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
  "extends": ["airbnb", "plugin:prettier/recommended"],
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "commonjs": true,
    "es6": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"]
      }
    }
  },
  "rules": {
    "import/extensions": [
      "error",
      "ignorePackages",
      {
        "js": "never",
        "jsx": "never",
        "ts": "never",
        "tsx": "never"
      }
    ]
  },
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.{ts,tsx}"],
      "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
      "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"],
      "extends": ["plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Just understand that using `@babel/eslint-parser` instead of the default parser `esprima` is because babel can lint on some experimental features (not much)

Comment: Thanks for this. We have a hybrid JS/TS codebase too (migrating everything slowly to TS) and would have never thought to override the parser for TS files.